# Does java consolidate multiple repaint() calls into a single repaint()?

Tags: java, timer, repaint, invokelater

I am receiving hundreds of events per second for a few seconds, each updates my model.  If I call `repaint()` inside of `invokeLater()` after every event, will repaint be called hundreds of times per second?  Is it smart enough to realise that it has 500 backed up `repaint()` and it only has to do 1?
I do not know when the events will pause, but I want to update the UI only at a reasonable rate.  I can implement a future that keeps getting updated until there is a long enough pause, say `500 ms`, but if java already does that, then why should i?

Comment: I don't think it matters how much you call repaint in a given time window, the paint function can only complete a certain number of updates given the refresh rate of any display (and double buffering is a thing that exists, and may be impactful). In short, don't know. Can't tell what you're really asking. But a 60Hz display only redraws 60 times a second. And a 120Hz display can manage 120 redraws in a second (but you probably can't draw that quickly with repaint in your application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **documentation** is such a good source of information.

From javadoc of [`repaint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--):

> *Note:* For more information on the paint mechanisms utilitized by AWT and Swing, including information on how to write the most efficient painting code, see [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

From [**Painting in AWT and Swing**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

> The program invokes `repaint()` on the component, which registers an **asynchronous** request to the AWT that this component needs to be repainted.
>
> The AWT causes the event dispatching thread to invoke `update()` on the component.
>
> *NOTE:* If multiple calls to `repaint()` occur on a component before the initial repaint request is processed, the **multiple requests may be collapsed** into a single call to `update()`. The algorithm for determining when multiple requests should be collapsed is implementation-dependent. If multiple requests are collapsed, the resulting update rectangle will be equal to the union of the rectangles contained in the collapsed requests.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, I reviewed the documentation but didn't stumble upon this explanation. This is exactly the answer I was looking for.